# Get Standard PricebookId in Apex Class

Tags: pricebook

I have a situation where I was querying standard pricebook with `SeeAlldata=true` in test class.

```
Pricebook2 pb2 = [select Id, Name, IsActive from PriceBook2 where IsStandard=True LIMIT 1];
```

Later I changed `SeeAlldata=false` and getting the id like this:

```
Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
```

Now I'm executing a method from test class in which I'm querying standard pridebook. I cannot use the `Test.getStandardPricebookId();` in apex class.

How can I fix this issue without setting `SeeAlldata=true`.

Comment: in that method put a condition like `if(Test.isrunningtest())
{
   Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();//Return getStandardPricebookId
}
else
{
   Pricebook2 pb2 = [select Id, Name, IsActive from PriceBook2 where IsStandard=True LIMIT 1]; //return query id
}`

Comment: `Test.isrunningtest()` is not the perfect solution as it will skip the query part. Check Ben's answer in this post https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BIGWIA4

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From my `Util.cls` library ...use a consistent entry point for fetching the StandardPricebookId across testmethods and PROD code

```
private static Pricebook2 stdPriceBook;  // Singleton, remember when first referenced

//  ------------------------------------------------------
//  getStdPricebookId : as of V31, testmethods can locate std pricebook wo seeAlldata=true
//  ------------------------------------------------------
public static ID getStdPricebookId() {
    if (Test.isRunningTest())   return Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    return getStdPricebook().id;    
} 

//  -------------------------------------------------------
//  getStdPriceBook: Singleton
//  -------------------------------------------------------
public static Pricebook2    getStdPriceBook () {
    if (stdPriceBook == null) 
        stdPriceBook    = [select id, name from Pricebook2 where isStandard = true limit 1];
    return stdPriceBook;    
}
```